# Pass complex object between action methods ASP.Net MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I studied most of the similar questions but couldn't find the answer!
Let me declare that I can define a simple TempData like an string,int and get it in another action method successfully, but

I have 3 parameters/variable in ActionMethod1 which is named "ExternalLoginCallBack", and need to ask a "UserName" from user on client side and then save the total 4 parameters in ActionMethod2 which is named "CreateExternalUser". 
This is what I have. 
AskUserNameView_NoActionMethod.cshtml as below:

```
@model ExternalUserViewModel

<form asp-action="CreateExternalUser" asp-controller="Account" method="post">        
        <label asp-for="UserName">Input your UserName Here: </label>
        <input asp-for="UserName" >                      
        <input  type="submit" value="ُSubmit"/>
</form>
```

(Using TempData) Attemp-No.1:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ActionMethod1

//some codes here

var externalLoginInfo = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
TempData["externalLoginInfo"] = externalLoginInfo;
TempData["email"] = email;
TempData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;

return View("AskUserNameView_NoActionMethod");
```

but instead of showing the AskUserNameView_NoActionMethod.cshtml it shows just a white page with no errors,no exception and nothing :
[image]

Attemp-No2: I removed  "ExternalLoginInfo" type and only two simple string as an object remained to pass to ActionMethod2:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ActionMethod1

//some codes here


var externalUserViewModel= new ExternalUserViewModel()
{   
Email = email,
ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
};   

TempData["externalUserViewModel"] = externalUserViewModel;

return View("AskUserNameView_NoActionMethod");
```

but again the white page above appeared. When I remove the complex TempData, my AskUserNameView_NoActionMethod.cshtml rendered successfully, and I can pass UserName which is entered by client side, to ActionMethod2. But without 3 other parameters which is needed to create a new External user !!

My ExternalUserViewModel is as below:

```
 public class ExternalUserViewModel
{
    public ExternalLoginInfo ExternalLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

and already added these codes to startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();

app.UseSession();
```

If TempData is not apllicable, I tried to pass my model with 3 parameters (Email,ReturnUrl,ExternalLoginInfo  ) to strongly typed AskUserNameView_NoActionMethod.cshtml, but again Username entered by client side,Email and returnedUrl passed to ActionMethod2 but externalLoginInfo  was null .

Summary: need an example to pass a complex data/object from actionmethod1 to actionmethod2 , without redirect to actionmethod2 !!

Answer (score 2):

You have two methods to achieve it.

As the TempData cannot store complex object here ,you can `Serialize` the object to json string and store it in TempData, then you can get the json string in CreateExternalUser action and `Deserialize` this json string to the correspond object as follow:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ActionMethod1()
    {

        //some codes here 
        var externalLoginInfo = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        TempData["externalLoginInfo"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(externalLoginInfo);
        TempData["email"] = email;
        TempData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        return View("AskUserNameView_NoActionMethod");

    }
```

Receive:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateExternalUser(UserName  userName)
        {
            //some codes here 
            var externalLoginInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExternalLoginInfo>(TempData["externalLoginInfo"].ToString());

           var email = TempData["email"] as string;
            var returnUrl = TempData["returnUrl"] as string;

            return View(); 
        }
```

Another method is to create `a custom method` named `TempDataExtensions` to pass object from an action to another.

```
public static class TempDataExtensions
{
    public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        tempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
    {
        object o;
        tempData.TryGetValue(key, out o);
        return o == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
    }
}
```

Store object:

```
var externalLoginInfo = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
TempData.Put("externalLoginInfo", externalLoginInfo);
```

Get object:

```
var externalLoginInfo = TempData.Get<ExternalLoginInfo>("externalLoginInfo");
```

Comment: @ehsan_kabiri_33 ,  If my answer helps you solve the problem, please mark it as the answer, and if there is a problem, please let me know.

Comment: Using :  TempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); results in error :This instance contains state that cannot be serialized and deserialized on this platform and using  : TempData["model"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, new JsonSerializerOptions
                      { MaxDepth = 64 });  it results in error : A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported- I tried some changes in startup.cs but no success got.

Comment: Your code is true. The problem is with  "externalLoginInfo", which creates a loop/cycle and results in error. I now can send simple objects by your code, but still having problem with assigning "externalLoginInfo " in the above to a TempData.